# Convert huge csv to hdf5 format

Tags: python, csv, bigdata, hdf5, vaex

I downloaded IBM's [Airline Reporting Carrier On-Time Performance Dataset](https://developer.ibm.com/data/airline); the uncompressed CSV is 84 GB.  I want to run an analysis, similar to [Flying high with Vaex](https://vaex.io/blog/flying-high-with-vaex-analysis-of-over-30-years-of-flight-data-in-python), with the vaex libary.

I tried to convert the CSV to a hdf5 file, to make it readable for the vaex libary:

```py
import time
import vaex
start=time.time()
df = vaex.from_csv(r"D:\airline.csv", convert=True, chunk_size=1000000)
end=time.time() 
print("Time:",(end-start),"Seconds")
```

I always get an error when running the code:

```
RuntimeError: Dirty entry flush destroy failed (file write failed: time = Fri Sep 30 17:58:55 2022
, filename = 'D:\airline.csv_chunk_8.hdf5', file descriptor = 7, errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', buf = 0000021EA8C6B128, total write size = 2040, bytes this sub-write = 2040, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 221133661).
```

Second run, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to flush file's cached information (file write failed: time = Fri Sep 30 20:18:19 2022
, filename = 'D:\airline.csv_chunk_18.hdf5', file descriptor = 7, errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', buf = 000002504659B828, total write size = 2048, bytes this sub-write = 2048, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 348515307)
```

Is there an alternative way to convert the CSV to hdf5 without Python? For example, a downloadable software which can do this job?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with vaex, so can't help with usage and functions. However, I can read error messages. :-)

It reports "bytes written" with a huge number (18_446_744_073_709_551_615), much larger than the 84GB CSV. Some possible explanations:

1. you ran out of disk
2. you ran out of memory, or
3. had some other error

To diagnose, try testing with a small csv file and see if `vaex.from_csv()` works as expected. I suggest the `lax_to_jfk.csv` file.

Regarding your question, *is there an alternative way to convert a csv to hdf5?*, why not use Python?

Are you more comfortable with other languages? If so, you can install HDF5 and write your code with their C or Fortran API.

OTOH, if you are familiar with Python, there are other packages you can use to read the CSV file and create the HDF5 file.

**Python packages to read the CSV**
Personally, I like NumPy's `genfromtxt()` to read the CSV (You can also use `loadtxt()` to read the CSV, if you don't have missing values and don't need the field names.) However, I think you will run into memory problems reading a 84GB file. That said, you can use the `skip_header` and `max_rows` parameters with `genfromtxt()` to read and load a subset of lines. Alternately you can use `csv.DictReader()`. It reads a line at a time. So, you avoid memory issues, but it could be very slow loading the HDF5 file.

**Python packages to create the HDF5 file**
I have used both h5py and pytables (aka tables) to create and read HDF5 files. Once you load the CSV data to a NumPy array, it's a snap to create the HDF5 dataset.

Here is a very simple example that reads the `lax_to_jfk.csv` data and loads to a HDF5 file.

```
csv_name = 'lax_to_jfk'
rec_arr = np.genfromtxt(csv_name+'.csv', delimiter=',',
                        dtype=None, names=True, encoding='bytes')

with h5py.File(csv_name+'.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset(csv_name,data=rec_arr)
```

**Update**:
After posting this example, I decided to test with a larger file (`airline_2m.csv`). It's 861 MB, and has 2M rows. I discovered the code above doesn't work. However, it's not because of the number of rows. The problem is the columns (field names). Turns out the data isn't as clean; there are 109 field names on row 1, and some rows have 111 columns of data. As a result,  the auto-generated dtype doesn't have a matching field. While investigating this, I also discovered many rows only have the values for first 56 fields. In other words, fields 57-111 are not very useful. One solution to this is to add the `usecols=()` parameter. Code below reflects this modification, and works with this test file. (I have not tried testing with your large file `airline.csv`. Given it's size likely you will need to read and load incrementally.)

```
csv_name = 'airline_2m'
rec_arr = np.genfromtxt(csv_name+'.csv', delimiter=',',
                        dtype=None, names=True, encoding='bytes') #,
                        usecols=(i for i in range(56)) )

with h5py.File(csv_name+'.h5', 'w') as h5f:
    h5f.create_dataset(csv_name,data=rec_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your example. I believe the problem you are facing is quite common when dealing with CSVs. The schema is not known.

Sometimes there are "mixed types" and pandas (used underneath vaex's `read_csv` or `from_csv` ) casts those columns as dtype `object`.

Vaex does not really support such mixed dtypes, and requires each column to be of a single uniform type (kind of a like a database).

So how to go around this? Well, the best way I can think of is to use the `dtype` argument to explicitly specify the types of all columns (or those that you suspect or know to have mixed types). I know this file has like 100+ columns and that's annoying.. but that is also kind of the price to pay when using a format such as CSV...

Another thing i noticed is the encoding.. using pure `pandas.read_csv` failed at some point because of encoding and requires one to add  `encoding="ISO-8859-1"`. This is also supported by `vaex.open` (since the args are just passed down to pandas).

In fact if you want to do manually what `vaex.open` does automatically for you (given that this CSV file might not be as clean as one would hope), do something like (this is pseudo code but I hope close to the real thing)

```
# Iterate over the file in chunks
for i, df_tmp in enumerate(pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=11_000_000, encoding="ISO-8859-1", dtype=dtype)):
    # Assert or check or do whatever needs doing to ensure column types are as they should be
    
    # Pass the data to vaex (this does not take extra RAM):
    df_vaex = vaex.from_pandas(df_tmp)
    # Export this chunk into HDF5
    # df_vaex.export_hdf5(f'chunk_{i}.hdf5')

# When the above loop finishes, just concat and export the data to a single file if needed (gives some performance benefit).
df = vaex.open('chunk*.hdf5')
df.export_hdf5('converted.hdf5', progress='rich')
```

I've seen potentially much better/faster way of doing this with vaex, but it is not released yet (i saw it in the code repo on github), so I will not go into it, but if you can install from source, and want me to elaborate further feel free to drop a comment.

Hope this at least gives some ideas on how to move forward.

EDIT:
In last couple of versions of vaex core, `vaex.open()` opens all CSV files lazily, so then just export to hdf5/arrow directly, it will do it in one go. Check the docs for more details: https://vaex.io/docs/guides/io.html#Text-based-file-formats